# optimize an array for interpolation

Tags: numpy, optimization, scipy, interpolation

I am using an array (51x51x181) to make a 3d interpolation in python (and I can calculate any point inbetween if needed).

I need to reduce the size of the array and would like to do this with the least amount of error possible.

Attached you find an example, with the error function I would like to improve on. The number of values in the array should stay the same, however the Angles and Shifts in the example do not have to be equally spaced.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator
import itertools
Data=np.zeros((5,180))
Angles=np.linspace(0,360,10)
Shifts=np.linspace(0,100,10)

Data=np.sin(np.deg2rad(Angles[:,None]+Shifts[None,:]))

interp = RegularGridInterpolator((Angles, Shifts),Data, bounds_error=False, fill_value=None)

def errorfunc():
    Angles=np.linspace(0,360,50)
    Shifts=np.linspace(0,100,50)

    Function_Results=np.sin(np.deg2rad(Angles[:,None]+Shifts[None,:]).flatten())
    Data_interp=interp(np.array(list(itertools.product(Angles,Shifts))))
    Error=np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square(Function_Results-Data_interp)))
    return(Error)
```

I could not find a feasible optimizer in scipy (tried some with poor performance). Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: _reduce the size of the array_ - by how much? A fixed amount? _least amount of error possible_ - how much error is tolerable? If you don't fix the error or size reduction then the problem has too many degrees of freedom

Comment: I need to reduce the size of the array, and live with the resulting error (in the example reduce the Axes for Angles and Shifts (both) to 1/5 of the original values).

Comment: I don't see how this gets to 51x51x181. In the inside of `errorfunc` you only get to 50x50.